# Merging List of data frames into a single data frame, or avoiding it altogether

Tags: r

I have a dataset like:

```
Company,Product,Users
MSFT,Office,1000
MSFT,VS,4000
GOOG,gmail,3203
GOOG,appengine,45454
MSFT,Windows,1500
APPL,iOS,6000
APPL,iCloud,3442
```

I'm writing a function to return a data frame with the nth product product for each company ranked by "Users" so the output of rankcompany(1) should be:

```
     Company   Prodcut Users
APPL    APPL       iOS  6000
GOOG    GOOG appengine 45454
MSFT    MSFT        VS  4000
```

The function looks like:

```
rankcompany <- function(num=1){

    #Read data file
    company_data <- read.csv("company.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    #split by company
    split_data <- split(company_data, company_data$Company)

    #sort and select the nth row
    selected <- lapply(split_data, function(df) {
                                                df <- df[order(-df$Users, df$Product),]
                                                df[num,]
                                                 })

    #compose output data frame
    #this part needs to be smarter??
    len <- length(selected)
    selected_df <- data.frame(Company=character(len),Prodcut=character(len), Users=integer(len),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    row.names(selected_df) <- names(selected)


    for (n in names(selected)){
        print(str(selected[[n]]))
        selected_df[n,] <- selected[[n]][1,]

    }

    selected_df
}
```

I split the input data frame into a list then perform the sorting and selection then try to merge the result into the output data frame "selected_df"

I'm new to R and I thin the merging can be done in a smarter way. Or should I avoid splitting in the first place? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: look at rbindlist from the package data.table to replace all the code after lapply

Comment: @DMT: tried it. Works fine but seems row names were lost in the output. it starts with an index instead of "APPL" for example.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in a much simpler way with `dplyr` :

```
rankcompany <- function(d, num=1) {
   d %>% group_by(Company) %>% arrange(desc(Users)) %>% slice(num)
}
```

And then you can do :

```
rankcompany(d,2)
```

or :

```
d %>% rankcompany(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comment from @DMT
I replaced the merging code with:

```
    selected_df <- rbindlist(selected)
    selected_df <- as.data.frame(selected_df)
    row.names(selected_df) <- names(selected)
    selected_df
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you like the clarity of `split` and `lapply` you can use a much shorter version of your function.

```
rankcompany <- function(N){
    byCompany <- split(df, sorted$Company)
    ranks <- lapply(byCompany,
             function(x)
             {
               r <- which(rank(-x$Users)==N)
               x[r,]
             })
    do.call("rbind", ranks)
}

rankcompany(1)

> rankcompany(1)
     Company   Product Users
APPL    MSFT        VS  4000
GOOG    GOOG appengine 45454
MSFT    APPL       iOS  6000
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `rbindlist`, you may not need to convert to `data.frame`  before doing this:

```
library(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
n <- 1L
setDT(company_data)[order(-Users), .SD[n], keyby=Company]
#   Company   Product Users
#1:    APPL       iOS  6000
#2:    GOOG appengine 45454
#3:    MSFT        VS  4000
```

`setDT` converts the `data.frame` to `data.table` *by reference* (without any additonal copy/memory usage). Then we sort the data.table in descending order by `Users` column, and then *group by* `company`, and for each group, we obtain the `n`th row from **S**ubset of **D**ata (`.SD`) for that group.

In your case, perhaps,

```
DT <- rbindlist(selected)
DT[order(-Users), .SD[n], keyby=Company]
```

But the previous solution is a much more efficient and easier one-liner to solve the issue.

#### data

```
company_data <-  structure(list(Company = c("MSFT", "MSFT", "GOOG", "GOOG", "MSFT", 
"APPL", "APPL"), Product = c("Office", "VS", "gmail", "appengine", 
"Windows", "iOS", "iCloud"), Users = c(1000L, 4000L, 3203L, 45454L, 
1500L, 6000L, 3442L)), .Names = c("Company", "Product", "Users"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```